# Why are my Cacti graphs showing a lot of question marks instead of letters?

Tags: linux, cacti

My Cacti graphs are showing normal except that graphs have [question marks below instead of the letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02LGW.png). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image: Image of graph]

Comment: looks like you are using national characters in the axis descriptions and legend. am I right ?

Comment: Yes,@drookie Do you have any ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: Yup, stop using them, or fix cacti environment.

Comment: Altought it is an old post, look if this helps: http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=42046